# Is there a way to schedule a cron job that does not run on the 3rd weekend of the month?

Tags: cron, posix

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Do you want it to run every day that is not part of the 3rd weekend, or do you want it to run every weekend day that is not the 3rd weekend?  If the Months starts on a Monday, is that the 1st weekend?

Answer (score 2):

Save the following as `/usr/local/bin/is_third_week_in_month.sh` or some place

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 3 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <yyyy> <mm> <dd>" 1>&2
    exit 127
fi

YEAR=$1
MONTH=$2
DAY=$3

FIRST_WEEK_IN_MONTH=`date +%V -d $YEAR-$MONTH-01`
WEEK_FOR_DAY=`date +%V -d $YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY`

DIFF=$(($WEEK_FOR_DAY - $FIRST_WEEK_IN_MONTH))

if [ $DIFF = 2 ]
then
    # this is the third week
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

and then add to crontab

```
12 00 * * 1,2,3,4,5  your_command
12 00 * * 6,7  test ! /usr/local/bin/is_third_week_in_month.sh `date "+%Y %m %d"` && your_command
```

Or you could modify the script to check for date as well if you want to only have one line in crontab.

Comment: On my system, date +%V prints a leading zero for single digit week numbers. That makes the calculation of $DIFF think it's got octal values and fail. Try running this script for 2009 02 19, for example. Strip the leading zero as follows: FIRST_WEEK_IN_MONTH=`date +%V -d $YEAR-$MONTH-01|sed s/^0//` --- and on the next line --- WEEK_FOR_DAY=`date +%V -d $YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY|sed s/^0//`

Comment: Also, the ISO week number (%V) for Jan 1 can be 52 (e.g. 2006) or 53 (e.g. 2005) which can cause th $DIFF calculation to be negative and fail to find week 3 in January. So you should change the "%V"s to "%W" which always starts the year in week zero or one and ends the year in week 52 or 53 (%V can end the year in 52, 53 or 1).

Answer (score 0):

Run it on the 1st, 2nd, 4th (and maybe 5th, it can happen) weekends.

```
# m h dom      mon dow   command
  * * 1-20,28-31 *   0     echo #test
```

I have no idea if that will run everyday, or just on Sundays (day 0), but it won't run on the 21st to 27th - the third week.  It may be simple enough to put a check in the script that will exit if it is the third week (or it's not a Sunday).

Comment: This won't actually work (at least not with vixie cron).  This will cause the script to run on days 1-20, 28-31, *and* every Sunday.  When dom and dow are specified, the script is run when either condition succeeds.

Comment: I stand corrected - but a check in the script for a 'not-sunday, so exit' would solve that. Then again, so would running it every sunday, and then exiting if was the 21st-27th.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run on any possible Saturday except the third one (try #3):

```
GREP=/usr/local/bin/grep
TODAY=/bin/date "+%d"
THIRD_SAT=/bin/date -v1d -v+1m -v-7d -v-sat "+%d"
#min hr day month weekday script
0    0  *   *     6       ($THIRD_SAT | $GREP $TODAY) || /bin/echo doit
```

Comment: This won't actually work (at least not with vixie cron).  This will cause the script to run on days 1-13, 21-31, *and* every Saturday.  When day of month and day of week are specified, the script is run when either condition succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I hadn't realized the last two columns are ORed instead of ANDed.  Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

1. make a cron job that runs a given script when needed ignoring the 3rd weekend part
2. make a cron job that runs on the 21 and another on the 28 to switch the script out and back for another no-op script.

Hacky but it would work